# How to stop echo every time I open a new terminal

Tags: cygwin

I used echo "cd your_path" >> ~/.bashrc to open Cygwin to a specific folder and I messed up the first two times using it and now every time I open up a new terminal I keep getting the following errors. [These appear at the top of the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxZMr.png) Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Edit your .bashrc. Obviously it contains `cd` commands to directories which don't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sorry for the long reply. I had to try something else.